# TypeScript filter tuple type by an arbitrary type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How would I go about generating a new tuple type by filtering a provided tuple type by an arbitrary type within the provided tuple?

Example ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAUg9gVwE4DsIigXigbQEQAmcKA5MHgDRQkDOwcYJVJARhADYCWEAbpygHMSAXQDcAWABQU0JCgBRAB4BjdggIQAYkjgBbACoIw7CAB59UCIuAQUBGlAQoA1ijgB3FDmFV5APiwoAH4QoIlpSVloABEIMCQIGhp+AXhkNAxsJVV1LR0DIxNTNNR0KkJiMjw-USgAejqoKKgaAAtEdgIoNlxaekZmNi5eFJEpIA)):

```js
type Journey = ["don't", 'stop', 'believing'];

type ExcludeFromTuple<T extends unknown[], E> = ????;

type DepressingJourney = ExcludeFromTuple<Journey, "don't">; // type should be ['stop', 'believing']
```

*Note that the solution doesn't need to ensure that type `E` exists in type `T` before hand, it just need to remove it if it does.*

Although the example is simple here, I have a more complicated use case where I want to be able to filter out by an arbitrary type defined by a consumer of the library I am writing.

Although TypeScript natively supports the [exclude type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu), it only works on union types, and I have been unable to find an equivalent for tuples.

A type like `ExcludeFromTuple` would be extremely useful for generating other utility types.

```
type RemoveStringsFromTuple<T extends unknown[]> = ExcludeFromTuple<T, string>;
type RemoveNumbersFromTuple<T extends unknown[]> = ExcludeFromTuple<T, number>;
type RemoveNeversFromTuple<T extends unknown[]> = ExcludeFromTuple<T, never>;
type RemoveUndefinedsFromTuple<T extends unknown[]> = ExcludeFromTuple<T, undefined>;
```

I have a feeling the type would need to leverage a combination of TypeScript 2.8’s [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types),
TypeScript 3.1’s [mapped types on tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), and some type of recursive type magic, but I haven't been able figure it out nor find anyone who has.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update for TS 4.1+:

With [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) introduced in TS 4.0, and [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) introduced in TS4.1, you can now write `ExcludeFromTuple` more simply as:

```
type ExcludeFromTuple<T extends readonly any[], E> =
    T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? [F] extends [E] ? ExcludeFromTuple<R, E> :
    [F, ...ExcludeFromTuple<R, E>] : []
```

You can verify that this works as desired:

```
type DepressingJourney = ExcludeFromTuple<Journey, "don't">;
// type should be ['stop', 'believing']

type SlicedPi = ExcludeFromTuple<[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9], 1 | 9>
// type SlicedPi = [3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 7]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUg9gVwE4DsIigXigbQEQAmcKA5MHgDRQkDOwcYJVJARhADYCWEAbpygHMSAXQDcAWABQU0JCgBRAB4BjdggIQAYkjgBbACoIw7CAB59UCIuAQUBGlCQQAhkRTsMzlCBzCq8gD4sKShQqAsrGzsHHH4AMwgkKE0qADp0+MSoACVhKAB+XE08yNt7XHk8wqVVdS0dAyMTU2z-IIAuELCcFKh01Jq1DW09Q2MzVoUAvPbcYSkZcGgAEQgwJxoafgF4ZDQMbEG6kcbx013UdCpCYjI8AIlJAHonqFloGgALRHYCKDZcLR6IxmGwuLxtiIFpJ3lAAMpcZQQAgABU4WAUKiG9VGTTMOAAzFQAIxUAAsJKoAFYqABOKgAJioADZqVQiVAaVAABx0qgAdjpfigxKgAB8oLSAlIXm8lvDEci0RjCeS2VAmVBWZz2ereVB+cIgA)

---

Pre TS-4.1 answer:

Yuck, this is something that really needs [recursive conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980) which are not supported in TypeScript yet.  If you want to use them you do so [at your own risk](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223#issuecomment-513187373).  Usually I'd rather write a type that *should* be recursive and then unroll it into a fixed depth.  So instead of `type F<X> = ...F<X>...`, I write `type F<X> = ...F0<X>...; type F0<X> = ...F1<X>...;`.

To write this I'd want to use basic "list processing" types for tuples, namely `Cons<H, T>` to prepend a type `H` onto a tuple `T`; `Head<T>` to get the first element of a tuple `T`, and `Tail<T>` to get the tuple `T` with the first element removed.  You can define those like this:

```
type Cons<H, T> = T extends readonly any[] ? ((h: H, ...t: T) => void) extends ((...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never : never;
type Tail<T extends readonly any[]> = ((...t: T) => void) extends ((h: any, ...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
type Head<T extends readonly any[]> = T[0];
```

Then the recursive type would look something like this:

```
/* type ExcludeFromTupleRecursive<T extends readonly any[], E> = 
     T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : 
     ExcludeFromTupleRecursive<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? 
     Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never; */
```

The idea is: take the tail of the tuple `T` and perform `ExcludeFromTupleRecursive` on it. That's the recursion.  Then, to the result, you should prepend the head of the tuple if and only if it doesn't match `E`.

But that's illegally circular, so I unroll it like this:

```
type ExcludeFromTuple<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : X0<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type X0<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : X1<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type X1<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : X2<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type X2<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : X3<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type X3<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : X4<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type X4<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : X5<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type X5<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : X6<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type X6<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : X7<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type X7<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : X8<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type X8<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : X9<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type X9<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : XA<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type XA<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : XB<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type XB<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : XC<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type XC<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : XD<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type XD<T extends readonly any[], E> = T["length"] extends 0 ? [] : XE<Tail<T>, E> extends infer X ? Head<T> extends E ? X : Cons<Head<T>, X> : never;
type XE<T extends readonly any[], E> = T; // bail out
```

Having fun yet?  Let's see if it works:

```
type DepressingJourney = ExcludeFromTuple<Journey, "don't">;
// type should be ['stop', 'believing']

type SlicedPi = ExcludeFromTuple<[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9], 1 | 9>
// type SlicedPi = [3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 7]
```

Looks good to me.

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAUg9gVwE4DsIigXigbQEQAmcKA5MHgDRQkDOwcYJVJARhADYCWEAbpygHMSAXQDcAWABQU0JCgBhYjQA8ACSoAVAHxYoGqBAAewCCgI0oSCAEMiKdhmsoQOYVAD8UABReAFgC4odSgAOjDgQI0ASiwdHjhOAhijEzMLHzCQpED+ADMIJCgAJRjMOISkj2KoQLQeApqoOoKJSVloDWtOdmV9FNNzSxs7BygnF2EdbAzwyNLyxOTjAfS-QPGqTOyoPIaS2Kh4xaqixuakVvag4d6DZbSh22JR8dcpvRwABjEpGXBoACihgAxuwEAQIAAxJBwAC2GgQYHYEFu-QeVie9kczlcVAB7w0+GRgmAvjwbjRg0+VVcjQAGp9el0eto8TpKRZdoU6VVVDdtHdUoMAVUeYFFCgVHzbL0tFQ6TparwWn85AzUfdBhiRtiJmzdIS8MSBKTyYKVlBqZ5aYE6QBGJndWX6jk7FD5bm8-nszUWEWeMUKJRqb3yxVNZUXVXQe0aoUWbXPXW4qD4g1E0wmskU32WmluW0AJkdLLlqZ98bdHqgPM80oIsvND39NcaEqloZr4fOl3+NeLfVziaxYxxwn12ENxtNOcrVtwBZrAGYS87y03BlzW3XvRu-aK28H62uFWdI721SvB5Xhy8xxOPkbMzO93nrYu6QAWVes9eure1tcMoCq6LaBu2IbAWWp5KvUUZtH2X5xhat7JuO66ThmJLZq+842jWACsP5lmm-7ug0gHHiBuZgYekqQQ2v4wRGcEXjGRHXihwxJqOeoYY+044a6eEfgAbMRLq5gBXpQa+tHikenbMT20Y1uJnHotxI6vOhaaYU+2FmsJ+b0gA7BJf5SeRno7rJoEHgp9FUdB3bnqpdLmRpWpaXefF6QJz5CbmIn0gAHBZpFWdWlG7vZAZ0R2UFhmerHueFXkJj5aEPlOgVGcFJm2gAnBFFYWtJtmMWVzYOUGTlKa5qUIWqJUZY8Oq8Sm-m5YZs4WiFtoAIKla+FVAVVcm1RBznJbBKrNTGw1tahnW6QSWFZvlc6FTWABCI1kdFMkTXFraOYlVWzSx81XHS+3LVlq05RtL7Ge+9LyAdUUUcdjaneBilJV2KU3Yhn0PZivldetBmbX1DwDTWAAiX2VmNzmTfF50MSejWg2qKMQx1OnPbDr0Fe9toAqj5XWdu41-TRU2A5dwNzfBt3U0TPEk-xGitKpSMQGAVg0DQ-ACPAyBoBg2BAqC4JQjC8KIsiyhS6g6BUIQxBkHgWitAA9IbUBXDQviIOwBBQGwuC0PQjDMGwXC8BLIi-AtUAAMpcMCEAEAACpwujy2CELQnCCJIiiOBLlQdpUJ+8dUARVBFVQhZUKJKdUHHUCp1AoVp1Qplp+hdpQAAPlARVaFIxum32PucH7gfB9gseJznUCZ1A2f57n3dF1ApnCEAA)

Comment: Wow this is beautiful and exactly what I was looking for. Official recursive conditional typing support would help out a ton, but the unrolled version works just fine for my use case. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can this be made to work with `never`? `ExcludeFromTuple<[string, never, number], never>` gives me `never` instead of `[string, number]`. In fact, no matter what I'm trying to exclude, if the tuple contains a never, I get `never` instead of a tuple.

Comment: @snarf Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/Na092w) fix it?  The problem is that the type here is distributive in union types, and `never` is considered the empty union and weird things happen.