# How to type filtered list?

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter

```
const list = ['rabbits', 'raccoons', 'reindeer', 'red pandas'] as const 
const filteredList = list.filter(e => e.includes('re'))
```

How to type `filteredList`? I think of `(typeof list[number])[]`, and TS is OK with this, but since `list[number]` is just a single item, the type is more like an array with repetitive items to me, e.g. `['reindeer', 'reindeer']` or `['red pandas', 'red pandas']`. I'm not sure if that is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually TypeScript infers `filteredList` as type `("rabbits" | "raccoons" | "reindeer" | "red pandas")[]` which is equal to `(typeof list[number])[]` and I think it's totally okay to go with that.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA2gcgE4EMBG+CUEmANDDrsKOKRTgKYJgAmjj25l2jrMAB1xtcpALoxRMUJFgAoGcgBmCOFE58AMklhpE0AHQq1nABSNUAPhiMDLYHACu7CKaaYAlB7kB6HzACYAD0AfiA)

---

If you wanted the most accurate type possible on `filteredList` you could use a custom helper type which filters `typeof list` at compile time. Then [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `filteredList` to that type. I came up with this inspired by [this answer on Variadic Tuple Types by @jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58986589/12834972).

Essentially, you check if an item in `list` is assignable to `${string}${U}${string}` where `U` is your filter criteria (e. g. `"re"`
). If so, the item is kept in the resulting tuple type. If not, it is removed.

```
type FilterTuple<
  T extends readonly any[],
  U extends string,
> = T extends readonly [infer F, ...infer R]
  ? [F] extends [`${string}${U}${string}`]
    ? [F, ...FilterTuple<R, U>]
    : FilterTuple<R, U>
  : [];

const list = ["rabbits", "raccoons", "reindeer", "red pandas"] as const;
const filteredList = list.filter((e) => e.includes("re")) as FilterTuple<
  typeof list,
  "re"
>;
// const filteredList: ["reindeer", "red pandas"]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgFQK5gRAPAKCijSggA9kA7AEwGcoUIBDage0oRCicpAG0AugBpCUAKqkKEGvVrAUcSgHMRAPigBeYpKp0GzNhy59FAM1SwhUAHS2zFgEoDRAfih8YAndL18ABgAkAN5yCsoAvsFikSHyikrhfs5ERG4eVrbW8EiomNh4DlZiqskpAFywiMjoWDi4heKqohWCANz4+ADG7HJQCHC9WnwARChMAEbjcMC0w1ajTJ3dPXNQoxCK1BCoq+vUUGA81EyzXidQ3ZRy7Ze9plWoENQAMgPAmn1v1vc5KAAUfwgAEpNOoINZFJ0EBgtrQ-uthkCQedstU8nVRKBIKxTJ85CIiAj8Kp2gB6UkXHrvH7VJ6vOQtdabbYoXaMfaHGgnYbOIA)